# Not working slider with multiple ul lists

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I have a problem with making working slider with multiple ul lists. I'm using splide slider and I'm not able to make the thing that I want. I wonder is it possible to change slider when you click on menu. For example if you click "blue" you will get slider with blue images and when you click "green" you will get green images.

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li')
const red = document.querySelector('.red')
const blue = document.querySelector('.blue')
const green = document.querySelector('.green')

const pickColor = (e) => {
    const origin = e.target;


    if (origin.dataset.colorName === "red") {
        red.classList.remove('is-hidden')
        blue.classList.add('is-hidden')
        green.classList.add('is-hidden')


    } else if (origin.dataset.colorName === "blue") {
        red.classList.add('is-hidden')
        blue.classList.remove('is-hidden')
        green.classList.add('is-hidden')
    } else if (origin.dataset.colorName === "green") {
        red.classList.add('is-hidden')
        blue.classList.add('is-hidden')
        green.classList.remove('is-hidden')
    }

}
menu.forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener('click', pickColor)
})
```

```css
ul li{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .menu li{
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .is-hidden{
    display:none !important;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@latest/dist/css/splide.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li data-color-name="red">red</li>
            <li data-color-name="blue">blue</li>
            <li data-color-name="green">green</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="splide">
            <div class="splide__track">
                <ul class="splide__list red">
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="splide__list is-hidden blue">
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="splide__list is-hidden green">
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000/" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000/" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@latest/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            new Splide('.splide', {
                perPage: 3,
                perMove: 1,
            }).mount();

        });
    </script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I've never used splide, I see your problem.
What is not working in your code is that you have one set of controls for all slides.
You need to separate your slides and give them unique classes.

So instead of

```
<div class="splide">
     <div class="splide__track">
         <ul class="splide__list red">
                ...
         </ul>
         <ul class="splide__list is-hidden blue">
                ...
         </ul>
         <ul class="splide__list is-hidden green">
                ...
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

do

```
 <div class="splide1">
     <div class="splide__track">
         <ul class="splide__list red">
                ...
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="splide2">
     <div class="splide__track">
         <ul class="splide__list is-hidden blue">
                ...
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="splide3">
     <div class="splide__track">
         <ul class="splide__list is-hidden green">
                ...
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and change

```
new Splide('.splide', {
            perPage: 3,
            perMove: 1,
        }).mount();
```

to

```
new Splide('.splide1', {
            perPage: 3,
            perMove: 1,
        }).mount();
new Splide('.splide2', {
            perPage: 3,
            perMove: 1,
        }).mount();
new Splide('.splide13', {
            perPage: 3,
            perMove: 1,
        }).mount();
```

and in your JS replace the selectors

```
const red = document.querySelector('.splide1')
const blue = document.querySelector('.splide2')
const green = document.querySelector('.splide3')
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I'm really apperciate that you explained me that :)

Answer (score 2):

Zergski saw the problem, but it's actually trickier. 
We need more than that. In short, this is a working version:

```
      [Codepen] https://codepen.io/vanco-pham/pen/abBRQPG
```

I changed the HTML structure, add a bit of CSS and JavaScript. If you want more detail, you can try Zergski solution to see the difference.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for :)

Comment: Right, I get it. heh.. So many years of coding and I still make rookie mistakes =P MaybeI should start testing my code again before answering.. All the best to you two! ^^